Maya Python: Drop down menu align with button
I'm relatively new to using python in Maya. I am trying to figure out how to align the drop down menu with a button. I would like for both the drop down menu and both the buttons to be aligned with each other. What I'm getting

def win(myWin):
    if cmds.window(myWin, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI(myWin)
    myWin = cmds.window(myWin, rtf = True, width=250, height=180)
    cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.text(label = 'Create Controllers and Change Colours', font = 'boldLabelFont')
    
    # Controllers
    cmds.separator(height = 20)
    ctrSelectMenu = cmds.optionMenu(label = 'Controller Type')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Circle X')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Circle Y')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Circle Z')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Cube'))
    cmds.separator(style = 'none', height = 5)
    cmds.button(label = 'Create', c = lambda x:createControls(ctrSelectMenu), width = 100, align = 'centre')
    
    # Colours
    cmds.separator(style = 'none', height = 20)
    clrSelectMenu = cmds.optionMenu(label = 'Controller Colour')
    
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Black')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Grey')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Light Grey')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'White')
    
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Maroon')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Red')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Rust Red')
    
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Dark Blue')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Indigo')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Blue')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Navy Blue')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Sky Blue')
    
    #cmds.separator(style = 'none', height = 5)
    cmds.button(label = 'Apply', c = lambda x:controllerColour(clrSelectMenu),width = 250, align = 'right')
    
    cmds.showWindow(myWin)
    cmds.window(myWin, e=True, width=250, height=180)
    
win('Create Controllers')


You need to make sure you have the proper parent objects assigned and in this case you could use rowColumnLayout
def win(myWin):
    if cmds.window(myWin, exists = True):
        cmds.deleteUI(myWin)
    myWin = cmds.window(myWin, rtf = True, width=250, height=180)
    baseCol = cmds.columnLayout()
    cmds.text(label = 'Create Controllers and Change Colours', font = 'boldLabelFont')
    
    # Controllers
    cmds.separator(style='in', height = 20, p=baseCol)
    baseRowClo = cmds.rowColumnLayout(nc=3, p=baseCol)
    ctrSelectMenu = cmds.optionMenu(label = 'Controller Type', p=baseRowClo)
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Circle X')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Circle Y')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Circle Z')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Cube')
    cmds.separator(style = 'none', height = 5)
    cmds.button(label = 'Create', c = lambda x:createControls(ctrSelectMenu), width = 100, align = 'centre', p=baseRowClo)
    # Colours
    cmds.separator(style = 'in', height = 20,  p=baseCol)
    clrSelectMenu = cmds.optionMenu(label = 'Controller Colour', p=baseRowClo)
    
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Black')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Grey')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Light Grey')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'White')
    
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Maroon')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Red')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Rust Red')
    
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Dark Blue')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Indigo')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Blue')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Navy Blue')
    cmds.menuItem(label = 'Sky Blue')
    cmds.separator(style = 'none', height = 5)
    
    cmds.button(label = 'Apply', c = lambda x:controllerColour(clrSelectMenu), align = 'right', p=baseRowClo)
    cmds.showWindow(myWin)
    cmds.window(myWin, e=True, width=250, height=180)
    
win('Create Controllers')


Thanks for helping me figure out parenting was required. Solved my issue :)
